# Show another bar chart on clicking a particular bar in the main bar chart without disappearing of original bar chart ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts, react-highcharts

```
    import React, {
  useState
} from "react";
import {
  render
} from "react-dom";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import drilldown from "highcharts/modules/drilldown.js";

drilldown(Highcharts);

export const DrillDown = () => {
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({
    chart: {
      type: "bar",
      height: 650,
      events: {
        drilldown: function(e) {
          console.log(e.seriesOptions)
          if (!e.seriesOptions) {
            var chart = this,
              drilldowns = {
                Ingredients: {
                  name: "Ingredients",
                  color: " #ff0000",
                  data: [
                    ["Nutrients", 22],
                    ["Sweetners", 13],
                    ["Organic/Natural", 2]
                  ],
                  enableMouseTracking: false
                },
                Taste: {
                  name: "Taste",
                  color: " #ff0000",
                  data: [
                    ["Baby's Choice", 37],
                    ["Parent's Choice", 5]
                  ],
                  enableMouseTracking: false
                }
              },
              drilldowns1 = {
                Ingredients: {
                  name: "Ingredients",
                  color: "#C8C6C6",
                  data: [
                    ["Nutrients", 4],
                    ["Sweetners", 2],
                    ["Organic/Natural", 2]
                  ],
                  enableMouseTracking: false
                },
                Taste: {
                  name: "Taste",
                  color: "#C8C6C6",
                  data: [
                    ["Baby's Choice", 9],
                    ["Parent's Choice", 4]
                  ],
                  enableMouseTracking: false
                }
              },
              drilldowns2 = {
                Ingredients: {
                  name: "Ingredients",
                  color: "yellow",
                  data: [
                    ["Nutrients", 0],
                    ["Sweetners", 0],
                    ["Organic/Natural", 0]
                  ],
                  enableMouseTracking: false
                },
                Taste: {
                  name: "Taste",
                  color: "yellow",
                  data: [{
                      name: "Baby's Choice",
                      y: 0,
                      drilldown: true
                    },
                    {
                      name: "Parent's Choice",
                      y: 0,
                      drilldown: true
                    }
                  ],
                  enableMouseTracking: false
                }
              },
              drilldowns3 = {
                Ingredients: {
                  name: "Ingredients",
                  color: "green",
                  data: [
                    ["Nutrients", 25],
                    ["Sweetners", 12],
                    ["Organic/Natural", 18]
                  ],
                  enableMouseTracking: false
                },
                Taste: {
                  name: "Taste",
                  color: "green",
                  data: [{
                      name: "Baby's Choice",
                      y: 42,
                      drilldown: true
                    },
                    {
                      name: "Parent's Choice",
                      y: 8,
                      drilldown: true
                    }
                  ],
                  enableMouseTracking: false
                }
              },
              series = drilldowns[e.point.name],
              series1 = drilldowns1[e.point.name],
              series2 = drilldowns2[e.point.name],
              series3 = drilldowns3[e.point.name];
            chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
            chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series1);
            chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series2);
            chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series3);
            chart.applyDrilldown();
          }
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: "Category Drivers",
      align: "left",
      style: {
        fontWeight: "200",
        fontSize: "2vw"
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: "category",
      style: {
        fontSize: "6vw"
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this) + "%";
        },
      },
      tickInterval: 10,
      stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: "gray",
          textOutline: 'none'
        }
      }
    },
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: ( // theme
          Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
          Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
        ) || 'gray',
        textOutline: 'none'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: true,
      reversed: true
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        stacking: "normal"
      },
      series: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
          style: {
            textShadow: false,
            fontSize: "1vw"
          }
        },
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
        name: "Negative",
        color: " #ff0000",
        data: [{
            name: "Baby Tolerance",
            y: 12,
            drilldown: false

          },
          {
            name: "Ingredients",
            y: 16,
            enableMouseTracking: true,
            drilldown: true
          },
          {
            name: "Health Benefits",
            y: 6,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Taste",
            y: 9,
            enableMouseTracking: true,
            drilldown: true
          },
          {
            name: "Peer Recommendation",
            y: 0.5,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Expert Advocacy",
            y: 2,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Brand Value",
            y: 3.5,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Convenience",
            y: 2,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Price",
            y: 3.5,
            drilldown: false
          }

        ],
        enableMouseTracking: false
      },
      {
        name: "Mixed",
        color: "#bfbfbf",
        data: [{
            name: "Baby Tolerance",
            y: 8,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Ingredients",
            y: 4,
            enableMouseTracking: true,
            drilldown: true
          },
          {
            name: "Health Benefits",
            y: 3,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Taste",
            y: 3,
            enableMouseTracking: true,
            drilldown: true
          },
          {
            name: "Peer Recommendation",
            y: 11,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Expert Advocacy",
            y: 3,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Brand Value",
            y: 0.5,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Convenience",
            y: 3,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Price",
            y: 0.5,
            drilldown: false
          }
        ],
        enableMouseTracking: false
      },
      {
        name: "Neutral",
        color: "#ffc000",
        data: [{
            name: "Baby Tolerance",
            y: 1,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Ingredients",
            y: 0,
            enableMouseTracking: true,
            drilldown: true
          },
          {
            name: "Health Benefits",
            y: 0,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Taste",
            y: 0,
            enableMouseTracking: true,
            drilldown: true
          },
          {
            name: "Peer Recommendation",
            y: 0,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Expert Advocacy",
            y: 0,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Brand Value",
            y: 0,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Convenience",
            y: 0,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Price",
            y: 0,
            drilldown: false
          }
        ],
        enableMouseTracking: false
      },
      {
        name: "Positive",
        color: " #00b050",
        data: [{
            name: "Baby Tolerance",
            y: 20,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Ingredients",
            y: 15,
            enableMouseTracking: true,
            drilldown: 'sad'
          },
          {
            name: "Health Benefits",
            y: 11,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Taste",
            y: 7,
            enableMouseTracking: true,
            drilldown: 'dsa'
          },
          {
            name: "Peer Recommendation",
            y: 5,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Expert Advocacy",
            y: 11,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Brand Value",
            y: 11,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Convenience",
            y: 6,
            drilldown: false
          },
          {
            name: "Price",
            y: 3,
            drilldown: false
          }
        ],
        enableMouseTracking: false
      }
    ],
    drilldown: {
      series: []
    }
  });

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    HighchartsReact highcharts = {
      Highcharts
    }
    options = {
      chartOptions
    }
    /> <
    /div>
  );
};
```

I am using recharts for designing the graphs in reactJS. I tried using drilldown function from highcharts to achieve another bar chart on clicking a particular bar of the original bar chart but I don't want the original graph to disappear. I want the original graph to decrease its[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryZIM.png) size and show the new bar chart on its right side.

Here is the code I have written.
And I don't want the original graph to disappear.

Here are the attached images that will be helpful.
On clicking the verbatim button, I have to achieve this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVbvo.png)

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is anybody able to figure out the problem in my code? Any kind of help will really be appreciated.